# Android Studio - Rewarded Video Ad loaded but not shown

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I tried the following code (main_activity.java)

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
// Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
```

logcat says, that the Ad is loaded but it doesn´t show up. I want to display the ad in a seperate fragment, so maybe the "(this)" is wrong?

Thank you for your help...
See this reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

Comment: Is something written in the logcat?

Comment: 11-13 19:14:29.822 19689-19689/com.appname I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-13 19:14:29.822 19689-19689/com.appname I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("825F1B66644B81609CEF1C71") to get test ads on this device.
11-13 19:14:30.551 19689-19689/com.appname I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
11-13 19:14:30.552 19689-19689/com.appname I/Ads: Ad finished loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
 @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy to find out what is that I am missing ,U saved my time !

Comment: RewardedVideoAd   how to open in my activity inside